# drag & rotate unity

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

Please, I need help to rotate an object by dragging. The object is a rudder of a boat to rotate with the touch screen. I have a problem, clicking on the object always returns to angle 0. Then if I can make it rotate, but it always starts from 0 and not from where I stay.

```
public void OnClick()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    baseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    baseAngle -= Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
}

public void OnDrag()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    float ang = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - baseAngle;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ang, Vector3.right);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but previous post is not right. Problem is a "default" direction of your cube (you use Vector.right, but you need Vector.up), and wrong axis of it. You may use "z" and "y", instead "y" and "z'. Im fix it now, end fully rewrite my answer.

```
private Vector2 GetDirectionToMouse()
{
    var mousePosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    Vector2 result = Input.mousePosition - mousePosition;
    return result;
}

float dragAngle;

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData data)
{
    var directionToMouse = GetDirectionToMouse().normalized;
    var mouseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(directionToMouse.y, directionToMouse.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    var transAngle = Mathf.Atan2(transform.up.z, transform.up.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    dragAngle = mouseAngle - transAngle;
}    

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
{
    var directionToMouse = GetDirectionToMouse().normalized;
    var mouseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(directionToMouse.y, directionToMouse.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    var targetAngle = mouseAngle - dragAngle;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(targetAngle, Vector3.right);
}
```

Comment: It still does not work, when you click on the cube to rotate, it does not start to rotate from where it was, then it works correctly as before.

Do you think you can try it on with a bucket and check it yourself?
Please help..

Comment: Thank you very much !!!!!!!! :)
it worked correctly.
Sorry to bother you, but after my problem was resolved I wanted to make another object but with the Touch and Drag spin on the X axis and I did not get it, since even though I spin on the X axis I have the problem that it is not always good I touch it back to the initial position and from there it begins to move.

Comment: @SergiyKlimkov . .. Since its working fine and rotating on X axis so can you please guide me how to rotate the object on Y axis ... have same functionality like its will rotate from the current rotation... thank you in advance!!